# Manually ack messages in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Previously I was reading all the messages present in the queue, but now I have to return specific amount of message based of users choice(count).

I try to change the for loop accordingly but its reading all the message because of auto acknowledge. So I tried changing it to manual in config file.

In my program how to ack message manually after reading msg(currently i am using AmqpTemplate to receive and i don't have reference of channel)?

```
    Properties properties = admin.getQueueProperties("queue_name");
    if(null != properties)
    {
        Integer messageCount = Integer.parseInt(properties.get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT").toString());          
        while(messageCount > 0)
        {
            Message msg = amqpTemplate.receive(queue_name);
            String value = new String(msg.getBody());
            
            valueList.add(value);
            messageCount--;
        }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciable, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AmqpTemplate#receive` autoack the message unless the channel is transacted. To control acknowledgement you could use `AmqpTemplate#execute` and do by hand the receive or the best way is to use a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` or even a `BlockingQueueConsumer`

Comment: @NicolasLabrot I didn't find execute method in AmqpTemplate, are you referring to something else. Yes i did set setAcknowledgeMode to MANUAL in SimpleMessageListenerContainer.

Comment: Sorry, I refer to `RabbitTemplate#execute` which is an implementation of `AmqpTemplate`

Comment: @NicolasLabrot could you please through some light on this. What is ChannelCallback, looks like I need a reference of channel which i don't have.

Comment: Have a look at the [`RabbitTemplate#receive` code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.java#L645) but I do not think it is the right way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot manually ack with the `receive()` method - use a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` for an event-driven consumer with MANUAL acks and a `ChannelAwareMessageListener`. Or, use the template's `execute()` method which gives you access to the `Channel` - but then you will be using the lower-level RabbitMQ API, not the `Message` abstraction.

**EDIT:**

You need to learn the underlying RabbitMQ Java API to use execute, but something like this will work...

```
    final int messageCount = 3;
    boolean result = template.execute(new ChannelCallback<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean doInRabbit(final Channel channel) throws Exception {
            int n = messageCount;
            channel.basicQos(messageCount); // prefetch
            long deliveryTag = 0;
            while (n > 0) {
                GetResponse result = channel.basicGet("si.test.queue", false);
                if (result != null) {
                    System.out.println(new String(result.getBody()));
                    deliveryTag = result.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag();
                    n--;
                }
                else {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            if (deliveryTag > 0) {
                channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, true);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: GaryRussell could you please point any sample code of how to use execute(), I am very new to this and i don't have much forum on this.Thanks in advance

Comment: It is customary to mark the answer as accepted (click the check mark) if it answers your question. This will help other users searching for the same answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell if we use the receive* methods, does Spring use the NONE mode or AUTO mode? meaning, is it letting RabbitMQ consider the messages to be auto-delivered or Spring does the ACK after reception of the message?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments, especially on a six-year-old answer. Ack mode only applies to listener containers. The template calls `basicAck` before returning. If you want to reject and requeue the message, you have to run the `receive()` method in a transaction and throw an exception so the `basicAck` is rolled back and the message will be requeued.